# MongoDB 4.4: input to $filter must be an array not long

Tags: database, mongodb

I've implemented the following aggregation in MongoDB 4.4.2 and it works fine:

```
[{
    $match: {
        "$expr": {
            "$and": [{
                "$not": "$history_to"
            }, ],
        },

    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        "path": "$used",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true,
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "ticket": "$$ROOT",
        "status": {
            "$map": {
                "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$status",
                        "as": "cstatus",
                        "cond": {
                            "$not": "$$cstatus.history_to",
                        },
                    },
                },
                "as": "status",
                "in": "$$status.value",
            },
        },
    }
}]
```

But when I try it in MongoDB 4.4.4 I encounter `input to $filter must be an array not long`.

If it's any help, I figured that the cause of this error has something to do with:

```
"cond": {
    "$not": "$$cstatus.history_to",
},
```

Since when I comment `$not` it works fine; At first I thought that maybe `$not` is not supported anymore but it is supported so I'm out of ideas.

## Some example documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6083ca1ce151beea45602e5d"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-04-24T07:34:52.947Z"),
    "ticket_id" : ObjectId("6083ca1c68badcedddd875ba"),
    "expire_at" : ISODate("2021-04-24T19:30:00Z"),
    "history_from" : ISODate("2021-04-24T07:34:52.992Z"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("604df7857d58ab06685ed02e"),
    "serial" : "116627138",
    "status" : [
        {
            "history_from" : ISODate("2021-04-24T07:34:52.985Z"),
            "history_created_by" : ObjectId("604df7857d58ab06685ed02e"),
            "value" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    ],
    "history_created_by" : ObjectId("604df7857d58ab06685ed02e")
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60713b0fe151beea45602e56"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("604df7857d58ab06685ed02e"),
    "ticket_id" : ObjectId("60713b0f68badcedddd875b8"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-04-10T05:43:43.228Z"),
    "history_created_by" : ObjectId("604df7857d58ab06685ed02e"),
    "status" : [
        {
            "history_created_by" : ObjectId("604df7857d58ab06685ed02e"),
            "value" : NumberLong(1),
            "history_from" : ISODate("2021-04-10T05:43:43.277Z")
        }
    ],
    "serial" : "538142578",
    "expire_at" : ISODate("2021-04-10T19:30:00Z"),
    "history_from" : ISODate("2021-04-10T05:43:43.281Z"),}
```

Comment: the `$status` field is not array, just confirm it should be array, and it would be more easy if you post some example documents.

Comment: @turivishal Excuse me but I didn't quite understand you...Your saying that `status` should be an array? I'll try to add some example documents.

Comment: yes status field should be an array.

Comment: @turivishal OK thanks I'll look into it...But why it works in 4.4.2 version but not in 4.4.4

Comment: i don't think it is version specific error, just read [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) input value should be an array.

Comment: @turivishal I've added some example documents. `status` is actually already an array.

Comment: It is working perfectly see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_qWb0yNl0mM), in mongodb 4.4.5, there are some documents having status field in other data type means not array.

Comment: @turivishal I checked my documents and, as you said, it's a case of mismatched types. I'll try to fix it and if you want write your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks good as per your example documents you can check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_qWb0yNl0mM),

> *But when I try it in MongoDB 4.4.4, I encounter input to `$filter` must be an array not long.*

It is not any MongoDB version specific issue, The error says provided field `status` as input in `$filter` is not array type it is long type, and `$filter` input should be an array type.

Definitely there are/is some document(s) having non array value in `status` field.

If you want to check you can match condition before `$filter` operation,

```
{ $match: { status: { $type: "array" } } } // 4 = "array"
```

This will filter documents by `status`, it should be an array type.